# External login with Oauth2

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a Django application with users through Django's auth, on the other side there is an Oauth2.0 server that already has all users and their permissions registered. My goal now is to integrate the Django app with the Oauth2.0 server so we won't have to administrate the users ourselves. This would make it so the when the users want to log into our app they are redirected to the Oauth2.0 login site and then redirected to the home of our app once they login successfully.

I think I understand how Oauth2.0 works but I have a couple of questions I couldn't find anywhere else.

Is the scenario I'm describing possible? As in the users would no longer have to be registered in our app and a 3rd party Auth server would provide access to our app or not.

Once I get the access token after the user login where is it safe to keep the access token? I was thinking I could save to AT as a session variable so as to keep the end user's session linked to his account which is external to our Django app.

Every time the user makes a request I would check the AT I'm keeping, if the verification is OK our app responds with the view, otherwise the user is redirected to the login. Is this flow correct or am I not understanding how this integration would work?

What would happen in the case the user is given more permissions but I hold an old token? How do I handle these cases?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a third-party application, like [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth). You can simply disable creating local accounts, and enable a single custom social provider that interacts with your OAuth2.0 authorization server.

As noted [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1275), the process of creating your own custom OAuth provider isn't documented, but shouldn't be too difficult.

*Once I get the access token after the user login where is it safe to keep the access token?*

Allauth will store the access token in the database. If you want to put it in the session too, you can, but there's no point unless you want the client to make requests to the resource server directly.

*Every time the user makes a request I would check the AT I'm keeping, if the verification is OK our app responds with the view, otherwise the user is redirected to the login. Is this flow correct or am I not understanding how this integration would work?*

That's fine. If your authorization server has no way to invalidate issued access tokens, though, you can just assume that the access token is good up until the expiration date.

*What would happen in the case the user is given more permissions but I hold an old token? How do I handle these cases?*

Just use the access token normally. If the resource server indicates that it's invalid, prompt the user to log in again. You will get a new access token for that user that reflects their current permissions.